# Collada files have empty visual_scene tag when they have a parent and are exported via BPY

Tags: python, parent, collada

Exporting Collada (DAE) files using BPY results in malformed files with an empty `visual_scene` tag, if the involved mesh has a parent. It works fine otherwise.
How can I fix it in case I want to keep the parent?

In particular, I'm importing a blend file with

```
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=file_path)
```

then I start iterating on `bpy.context.scene.objects` looking for an object with a certain name. I select it with

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# Select the current mesh object
select_hierarchy(_object)
```

where `select_hierarchy()` is

```
def select_hierarchy(obj):
    obj.select_set(True)
    for child in obj.children:
        select_hierarchy(child)
```

and then export it with

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=file_path,
                          check_existing=False,
                          selected=True,
                          use_texture_copies=True,
                          include_children=True)
```

As said above, the output file is corrupted if the selected object has a parent, while it works fine if I do

```
_object.parent = None
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

right before exporting it.

I'm using Blender 4.0.1 and BPY 4.0.0

Comment: Hello ! This looks like a bug that should be posted as an official bug report, but can you also post a snippet of your script ?

Comment: Done  https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/118901